# Changing Style Inside LaTeX Listing

Tags: listings

In short, I'm trying to combine some C code with its disassembly in LaTeX such that the x86 code is displayed after the relevant statement. In order to make this look nice, I would like to be able to switch between styles inside of a listing. I've searched online for quite a while and have come across multiple sources talking about `escapeinside` and `escapechar` ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771799/latex-and-listings-highlighting-some-parts-of-the-code) for example), but I can't seem to get either working. Right now, my code looks like:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=customcpp, escapechar=\@]
void sort(int *rgList, int nLen)
{@\lstset{escapechar=\@, style=customasm}@
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 48h
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

where `customcpp` and `customasm` are styles that I have defined. Both work fine separately. It's when I try and combine them that I get issues. I have a feeling that I'm doing something stupid, but I can't seem to find it.

For what it's worth, here are my style definitions:

```
\lstdefinestyle{customcpp}{
   belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
   breaklines=true,
   frame=L,
   xleftmargin=\parindent,
   language=C++,
   showstringspaces=false,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\itshape\color{green},
   stringstyle=\color{purple},
   identifierstyle=\color{gray},
   tabsize=4,
   numbers=left,
   numbersep=8pt,
   stepnumber=1,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
}

\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{
   belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
   frame=L,
   xleftmargin=\parindent,
   language=[x86masm]Assembler,
   basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
   commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
   keywordstyle=\color{black},
   identifierstyle=\color{black},
   tabsize=4,
   numbers=left,
   numbersep=8pt,
   stepnumber=1,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}
}
```

I should also note that escaping *works*. What doesn't work is changing the style.

Comment: I may be wrong (I'm still learning about `listings`), but I think the style is set early on by the `lstlisting` environment, and you cannot simply switch from one to another *within* the listing. I'm afraid that's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround where I just used `@\verb=...=@` since that was the same format as my assembly code and it worked OKAY and I apparently can't use `\lstinline` inside of a listing. Nevertheless, it's still really silly that I had to resort to this. If anyone has any better solution, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).